# Getting first day of month from a selected month

Tags: php, mysql

```
$selectedmonth = '09';
$selectedyear = '2019';
$selecteduser = '1';
```

Let say i have variable like above and my mysql query like this

```
SELECT `USERID`, `CHECKTIME` 
FROM `checkinout` 
WHERE 
    USERID='$selecteduser' AND 
    YEAR(CHECKTIME)= '$selectedyear' AND
    MONTH(CHECKTIME)='$selectedmonth';
```

How do i modify my mysql query to search for the record for selectedmonth and first day of next month of the selectedmonth ?

Comment: `WHERE CHECKTIME BETWEEN '$selectedyear-$selectedmonth-01' AND '$selectedyear-$selectedmonth-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

Comment: Note that you're open to sql injection. See about prepared and bound queries

Comment: Thanks @Akina but i got the result for selected month only

Comment: @Strawberry noted with that ..this is just for testing purpose

Comment: If I had a nickel...